Two stacked area plots on the same chart
Plotting assets
I'm plotting $MSTR assets as follows
fig = px.area(df_all, x='end', y='val', color='fact', title=f'{symbol.upper()} : Balance sheet', width=1000, height=600)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_assets['end'], y=df_assets['val'], mode='lines', name='Assets'))

st.plotly_chart(fig)


Plotting liabilities
Similarly, I'm plotting liabilities like this (these show up as negative):
fig = px.area(df_all_liabilities, x='end', y='val', color='fact', title=f'{symbol.upper()} : Balance sheet', width=1000, height=600)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_liabilities['end'], y=df_liabilities['val'], mode='lines', name='Liabilities'))

st.plotly_chart(fig)


Question
Is there a way to have both of these on the same chart?

You can use plotly.graph_objects to add graphs in a loop process on a per-category basis, or you can reuse graph data created using px.area. I didn't have any data to reproduce for your question, so I used the examples in the reference to create a graph with subplots. By setting the spacing between the upper and lower graphs to zero, I made it look like a single graph. Depending on your data, some adjustments may be necessary.
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.gapminder()
df['pop2'] = df['pop']*-1

fig_t = px.area(df, x="year", y="pop", color="continent", line_group="country")
fig_b = px.area(df, x="year", y="pop2", color="continent", line_group="country")

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,
                    shared_xaxes=True,
                    vertical_spacing=0,
                    specs=[[{'type': 'scatter'}], [{'type': 'scatter'}]],
                   )

for i in range(len(fig_t.data)):
    fig.add_trace(fig_t.data[i], row=1, col=1)
    
for k in range(len(fig_b.data)):
    fig.add_trace(fig_b.data[k], row=2, col=1)
    
fig.show()


